# Indexing correctly within a for-loop and while-loop

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, while-loop

I have a set of brand numbers for a webpage url. I convert the webpage url into an f-string, and apply the brand number where it's supposed to. Each page has a unique ID to load the next page. I'm trying to extract this next page whilst matching the brand number the Id belongs to.

Here's some sample code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

brands = [989,1344,474,1237,886,1,328,2188]

testid = {}
for b in brands:
    url = f'https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands={b}&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance'
    payload={}
    headers = {}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    test= pd.read_json(StringIO(response.text), lines=True)
    for m in test['meta'].items():
        if m[1]['hasMore'] == True:
            testid[str(b)]= [m[1]['cursor']]
        else:
            continue
    for br in testid.keys():
        while True:
            html = f'https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands={br}&cursor={testid[str(br)][-1]}&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance'
            r = requests.request("GET",html, headers=headers, data=payload)
            read_id = pd.read_json(StringIO(r.text), lines=True)
            for m in read_id['meta'].items():
                try:
                    testid[str(br)].append(m[1]['cursor'])
                except:
                    continue
```

Here's the output it produces:

```
{'989': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMwODcw']}
```

However, it replaces the values originally in the brand number and only leaves the last one collected. It should leave a list and produce something like this:

```
{'989': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDI4Mzk1', ...],
 '1344': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDI4Mzk2', ...],
 '474': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDI4Mzk3', ...],
 '1237': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDI4Mzk3', ...],
 '886': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDI4Mzk4', ...],
 '1': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDI4Mzk4', ...],
 '328': ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDI4Mzk5', ...],
```

Where the triple dots `...` denotes the additional ID values collected from the page with that brand number. How can I get an output like this?

Comment: You might want to change `testid = {}` to `testid = collections.defaultdict(list)` then you can `testid[str(b)].append([m[1]['cursor']])`

Comment: @JonSG Does not make a difference for my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the `testid` list to be a `collections.defaultdict(list)` the rest falls out in a rather straightforward manner..

**Note:** I'm only going to fetch the first 3 cursors of any product but you can do them all as you like.

```
import collections
import requests

brands = [989,1344,474,1237,886,1,328,2188]
testid = collections.defaultdict(list)
for b in brands:
    headers = {}
    payload={}
    url = f"https://webapi.depop.com/api/v2/search/products/?brands={b}&itemsPerPage=24&country=gb&currency=GBP&sort=relevance"

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    data = response.json()
    i = 0 # short circuit 

    while data.get("meta", {}).get("hasMore") and i < 3:
        cursor = data.get("meta", {}).get("cursor")
        testid[str(b)].append(cursor)
        response = requests.request("GET", f"{url}&cursor={cursor}", headers=headers, data=payload)
        data = response.json()
        i += 1

for key, value in testid.items():
    print(key, value)
```

This gives us:

```
989  ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMzMjM0']
1344 ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMzMjM1', 'M3w0OHwxNjQwMDMzMjM1', 'NHw3MnwxNjQwMDMzMjM1']
474  ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMzMjM3', 'M3w0OHwxNjQwMDMzMjM3', 'NHw3MnwxNjQwMDMzMjM3']
1237 ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMzMjM5', 'M3w0OHwxNjQwMDMzMjM5', 'NHw3MnwxNjQwMDMzMjM5']
886  ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMzMjQz', 'M3w0OHwxNjQwMDMzMjQz', 'NHw3MnwxNjQwMDMzMjQz']
1    ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMzMjQ4', 'M3w0OHwxNjQwMDMzMjQ4', 'NHw3MnwxNjQwMDMzMjQ4']
328  ['MnwyNHwxNjQwMDMzMjUz', 'M3w0OHwxNjQwMDMzMjUz', 'NHw3MnwxNjQwMDMzMjUz']
```

Wait a sec.... What is going on with:

```
data.get("meta", {}).get("hasMore")
```

Great question and I should have explained it before.

So, there is a chance that `data.meta` is not defined and if that was true, the following would fail;

```
data["meta"].get("hasMore")
```

as would

```
data.get("meta").get("hasMore")
```

So what we did:

```
data.get("meta", {}).get("hasMore")
```

was use the second parameter of `get()` to provide a default value. In this case it is just an empty `dict` but that is enough for us to safely chain the followup `.get("hasMore")` onto.

Comment: This is brilliant! could you please explain a little about what you are doing with `data.get("meta", {}).get("hasMore")` so I get a better understanding of your approach?